# Javascript/jQuery problem - multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#kartyaazonosito" ).on( "focusout", function() {
console.log( $( this ).val() ); // I need the actual input value (from the actual line)
});

$( "#biztonsagikod" ).on( "focusout", function() {
console.log( $( this ).val() );// I need the actual input value (from the actual line)
});

});
```

1."line":

```
<input placeholder=" " class="o-input__field" type="text" name="cards[0].code" id="biztonsagikod" />
```

2."line":

```
<input placeholder=" " class="o-input__field" type="text" name="cards[1].code" id="biztonsagikod" />
```

The users can be add more and more "lines".
The on focusout works only for the 1. "line". How can I solve that, the focusout works the 2."line", and 3. line, etc..

Comment: IDs have to be unique per document, you should use a class instead

Comment: `<input class="o-input__field biztonsagikod"...` then `$(".biztonsagikod").on(...` - also assumes they aren't added after your jquery runs (which doesn't appear to be the case as it "works for line 1")

Comment: Thanks! It's working with your solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a common function and put it as onfocusout event instead.

```js
function myFunction(x) {   
     console.log( x.value );
}
```

```html
<input placeholder=" " class="o-input__field" type="text" name="cards[0].code" onfocusout="myFunction(this)" />
<input placeholder=" " class="o-input__field" type="text" name="cards[1].code" onfocusout="myFunction(this)" />
```

Comment: Thanks! It's great! :)